# Schnorr signature | Schnorr Public Parameters

Tags: encryption, discrete-logarithm, schnorr-signature

hello guys hope you are doing well :),

i am trying to simulate the Schnorr Signature, but i have encountered some difficulties finding the generator,

i have chosen a prime **P of 1024bit** and took a factor of **160bit as Q** but for the generator i'm trying to produce,

i'm using the equation => **g^Q = 1 mod P**

how can i implement this in python, and if this approach is not good please guide me...

thanks.

Comment: You can use this "1024-bit MODP Group with 160-bit Prime Order Subgroup" here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5114#section-2.1

Comment: how does this method differ from using elliptic curve?

Comment: Schnorr signatures with elliptic curves are very similar to signatures with MODP groups, and will be much more compact.

Comment: thank you very much dear :)